# Rhodecode -- How to see utf8 commits in hg

Tags: encoding, mercurial, rhodecode

When we using hg repository in rhodecode, all our utf8 commits(Cyrillic) are shown as question mark. Console tests:

```
user@host:~/src/project$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
user@host:~/src/project$ hg log --rev f263422d9a6c
changeset:   249:f263422d9a6c
date:        Mon Dec 15 11:19:16 2014 +0500
summary:     checkin - seatmap ?????????? ??????: ????? ???? ?? ???????? ?? ?????????

user@host:~/src/project$ export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
user@host:~/src/project$ hg log --rev f263422d9a6c
набор изм-й:   249:f263422d9a6c
дата:          Mon Dec 15 11:19:16 2014 +0500
сводка:        checkin - seatmap исправляем ошибку
```

Screen-shot from Rhodecode:

[image]

May be it somehow connected with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329034/mercurial-commit-messages-and-log-what-encoding-is-supported-does-hg-care-at-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify multiple encoding in the .ini file of RhodeCode

Please try setting:

default_encoding = CP1251,UTF-8

Comment: Thank you! This setting fixed the issue: default_encoding = UTF-8,CP1251. Default was default_encoding = utf8